# Fitting image inside a button

Tags: android, xml, button

Part of my xml code for my buttons.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bs2" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

the problem here is as u see the backspace arrow ( left arrow ) doesn't fit in the button i tried to make the .png file bigger ( tried 48,64,80 and 120 ) also tried gravity and layout_gravity didn't get any results.

so basically i want the arrow to be wider or it should be in middle for a good visual look.

so i would love any advice which will help without messing the layout.

[image]

Comment: Instead of Button you can use ImageButton.

Comment: @SilentKiller if possible i would like that to not happen because my buttons aren't custom and i kinda made my theme with this. Any way to make this work ?

Comment: but in the code you are using `Button` default one. show your theme code.

Comment: @SilentKiller yes the button is default. Ok i somehow didn't expect the image button to have the default background :/ still i cant make the button sit in layout like the rest any ideas on that ?

Comment: Provide your arrow image as well as background image.'

Comment: @SilentKiller there is no background image 
the arrow is http://galleryhip.com/black-left-arrow-icon.html something like this i edited a bit at photoshop.

Comment: you'll need two images one for background and another for Source if you want to show like other buttons. as you are using drawableLeft the arrow is comming right side.button is gettind

Comment: @SilentKiller added a 2nd screen to show whats the problem at the moment ( thought u are getting me wrong ) all my buttons have the same scaling ( when i change image button to button its good on layout like 1st screen but arrow isn't fit ) but the result is due to imagebuton the scaling at my 3rd row layout is broken.

Comment: are you using Background image.?

Comment: @SilentKiller as i said before no i don't use any background image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59101/discussion-between-silentkiller-and-wince).

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageButton instead of button and keep arrows image as a source for your button

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
```

Comment: having problems on adjusting that in the layout unlike the button it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Button` you can use `ImageButton`

to get Arrow in center you should use `android:scaleType="center"`

**Updated :**

as you are using `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bs2"` it will show leftside only.

if you want to use Image with Button you should use ImageButton but for that you need to use Two Images or common style for all Buttons. you can achieve by following way.

Try Following Code.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/back" />
```

[image]

Comment: nope due to my linear layout the " wrap_content" with back ground ends up making my layout look like mess.

Comment: Check Updated One @Wince